# in ddms prespective file explorer window is not displayed. Can anyone help me in viewing this window

Tags: android

Also please tell me, I want to play video from my local raw folder. my coding are

```
mPath.setText(("file:///Android_raw/toys.3gp"));
```

But error is video cannot be played.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open File explorer By opening DDMS tab.
After Selecting DDMs, the file explorer tab will be displayed. if it is not visible means it is taking some time to load file explorer. or else you can Restart your eclipse.

Then for playing video

```
VideoView myVideoView;
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.packagename/"+R.raw.videofilename);
myVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
```

In above code

instead of com.packagename  put your package name.

instead of videofilename put your video file name.

That's it... I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the `File Explorer` tab this way.

**Window --> Show View --> File Explorer**

If you don't see `File Explorer` in `Show View`, then do this.

**Window --> Show View --> Other** & then search for **File Explorer** in it.

Comment: and regd your other question, post the code snippet and the logcat, to get a better idea about that.

Comment: i had my video on my sdcard. what i meant here is i couldn't play my sdcard vide... anyways thanks for ur help. now i can play videos